# How do you set Windows CE 6.5 to landscape only using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, windows-ce, landscape

I am writing an application for Windows CE 6.5 in C#. The device will be mounted on a wrist strap so will always be in the landscape position, so I have designed the app accordingly. The problem is when you move the device when working the device switches between Portrait and Landscape. This is quite annoying and will also defeat the purpose of the program as it will slow down the users if they have to wait for the device to switch to landscape every time they want to use it.

I have researched this but have not found a working solution. I know in previous versions of CE you can set Right Handed/ Left Handed Landscape but I have checked and that option is nowhere to be found on this device.

Is there any way of programatically setting the orientation so that it does not change?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;`?

Comment: Probably missing something obvious but I am getting this error: Error 1 The name 'DisplayInformation' does not exist in the current context